# android implement app work on battery restriction mode

Tags: android, battery, restrictions, battery-saver

The quesion is that is it possible to implement my app works on battery restriction mode. If user enable the mode in my settings i don`t use wake lock anymore and more draining battery works.I have read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/enterprise/app-restrictions.html) article.